# Installing Nvidia drivers on Red Hat

Tags: drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am trying to install Nvidia drivers on Red Hat

Why am I getting the following error:

```
rpm -i NVIDIA_kernel-1.0-2880.rh62.i386.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
    kernel = 2.2.14-5.0 is needed by NVIDIA_kernel-1.0-2880.rh62.i386
[root@INEICP-EPM-W134 Downloads]# uname -a
Linux INEICP-EPM-W134 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Nov 9 08:03:13 EST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have kernel 2.6. WHy is it crying about kernel 2.2 ?

Comment: Are you running `Red Hat Linux 6.2` or `Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.2` ? They are very different, with RH6.2 coming from the 2.2 Kernel times.

Comment: I am running enterprise.

Comment: You habe `NVIDIA_kernel-1.0-2880.rh62.i386.rpm` which is for the ancient RH6.2, but you need nVidia drivers for RHEL6.2 - it is simply the wrong package.

Comment: Current nVidia drivers should be available from the EPEL repository AFAIK

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Do I need licence to download from EPEL?

Comment: No, EPEL works with CentOS, RHEL or whatever is binary-compatible  and has no access restrictions.